# Storing final token of a string using strtok()?

Tags: c, string, strtok

Say I have a string called str of the format

```
"token1, token2, token3"
```

and I want to store each token into its own char array like so

```
char* tok1 = strtok(str, ", ");
char* tok2 = strtok(str, ", ");
char* tok3 = strtok(str, "\0"); //this line is incorrect
```

But I get an error on the third token because strtok() expects a non-null input. Since strtok() requires two parameters (a string and a delimiter), how would I retrieve that final token?

Comment: There's no effective difference between `"\0"` and `""`. You can't have `\0` as a real character in a string, since it's the null terminator.

Comment: Then what should I put as the delimiter for that final token? There's no other value after it besides the null terminator. Would it just be ""?

Comment: Just use `""` since you don't need to look for a delimiter.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: The second line is incorrect too — you should use NULL as the first argument on the second and subsequent calls.

Comment: "*store each token into its own char array*" `tok1`, `tok2` and `tok3` *aren't* arrays but **pointers**. So the tokens are not stores there. Those pointers just point "into" the original `char`-array (`str`);

Comment: BTW, reading [documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8) mostly is a useful thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you are parsing the same string, the value of the first parameter must be `NULL` for all subsequent calls:

```
char* tok1 = strtok(str, ", ");
char* tok2 = strtok(NULL, ", ");
char* tok3 = strtok(NULL, "");
```

> On  the first  call  to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same  string,  str  should  be NULL.